# Слово "обязательно" всегда требует сказуемого (если это не отдельное предложение)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> После этого нам обязательно поужинать в горах, над лучшими погребами
>   региона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не всегда, если я правильно понял вопрос. Например, в статье на это слово из Грамоты:

> Выполнение законов обязательно для всех.

Мне кажется, что в роли *наречия **обязательно*** всегда требует сказуемого, а в роли *краткого прилагательного* требует дополнения.

Comment: Не, а тут-то как выкручиваться? Предложи пару глагольчиков!

Comment: Обязательно стоит поужинать, например.

Comment: Нужно добавить "нужно".